# Realtek retask pins in Windows 10

Tags: windows, audio, remap

How do I remap or retask pins in realtek drivers ver. 6.0.1(the latest drivers) in Windows 10?
I know there is something related to registry entries and modifying them, but they just don't apply after a restart. All I wanted to do is just reassign the blue and pink jacks on the back of my computer to be a headphone out and a mic in respectively, currently I have this setup:

```
Rear Blue: Line-In
Rear Green: Front Speakers
Rear Pink: Mic-In
```

The front green and front pink are not connected to the motherboard and in the driver settings there is no option besides the BIOS to disable them

Answer (score 1):

I remapped my pins using the registry on Windows 8, but after upgrading to Windows 10, the settings had no effect any more. I found a way to configure it with the Realtek software:

1. Open Realtek HD Audio Manager (double click icon in tray)
2. You should see graphics of the pins at the right
3. Right-click the pin to remap and select first entry in the context menu
4. Select the desired function

Unfortunately, all settings are lost after a reboot. Maybe it is just an issue on my machine, because I have not done a fresh installation.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.overclock.net/forum/6-intel-motherboards/378475-realtek-hd-audio-manager-universal-jack-retasking-ip35-pro-xe-4.html

It can't be done, anymore, without going back an older driver.  The driver simply resets the values every time it is initialized.